About Let’s Encrypt's certification renew and nginx
I'm doing the Let’s Encrypt for the firs time and this 101 question might quite possibly have been answered somewhere, but anyway, from https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#setting-up-automated-renewal

Most Certbot installations come with automatic renewals preconfigured. This is done by means of a scheduled task which runs certbot renew periodically.

So, to simplify things, I'm using the Certbot docker container to get certificate, and that container does not come with automatic renewals preconfigured, thus I need to enable that functionality myself.
The scheduled cron task is pretty straightforward:
0 0,12 * * * root sleep $SLEEPTIME && certbot renew -q
My question is, Let's Encrypt certificates is good for three months,  but this official recommendation from the Certbot document says that we need to try renewal every 12 hours.
This looks really excessive to me. Anyone know how soon we can do the renewal? (As from Update "let's encrypt" certificate from command line I know that there is no --force-renewal option)
I meant, if the renewal can happen 10 days ahead, then my cron job can be set every 5 days, if 6 days ahead, I'll use 3.
Also anyone knows if certbot renew's return code can be used to notify my script to trigger my nginx config reload after the renewal indeed happens?
Thanks

Running certbot every 12 hours is harmless. If a certificate is available for renewal, it will renew; if not, nothing happens besides a few API calls. certbot supports hooks for running commands, the docs even have an example of using hooks to start and stop nginx on renewing (a bit further up from the section you're on)

"If a certificate is available for renewal, it will renew". The problem is, how can it tell? Those API calls are made to Let's Encrypt or whatever places issuing / holding the certificates right? And there's millions of machines doing that.

Put another way: what exactly is it about running every 12 hours that is bothering you?

When can you renew?
From their FAQ (emphasis mine)

Our certificates are valid for 90 days. You can read about why here.
There is no way to adjust this, there are no exceptions. We recommend automatically renewing your certificates every 60 days.

Given they recommend renewing every 60 days, then it's safe to assume they are renewable at least 30 days before expiry.
Note that certbot automatically checks the certificate expiry against the system clock and so does not dial out to any API when the certificate has more than 30 days left before expiry. (reference)
How frequently should it run?

This looks really excessive to me. Anyone know how soon we can do the renewal? (As from Update "let's encrypt" certificate from command line I know that there is no --force-renewal option)
I meant, if the renewal can happen 10 days ahead, then my cron job can be set every 5 days, if 6 days ahead, I'll use 3.

I'd be cautious with this, don't cut it too small. You can slow it down a bit, but remember that if certbot fails there is no immediate retry (it can randomly fail for any reason) . You want to ensure that if it fails, it has many opertunities to retry and succeed before expiry.  Nobody likes their services failing due to TLS/SSL errors.
Triggering Reload:

So, to simplify things, I'm using the Certbot docker container to get certificate
...
Also anyone knows if certbot renew's return code can be used to notify my script to trigger my nginx config reload after the renewal indeed happens?

Oddly this is one thing that can be subtly more complex to run in docker.  The canonical way to run nginx config reload is to use a deployment hook using --deploy-hook <script>.
Outside of docker, you'd just use the script to directly trigger the nginx config reload.  Inside docker, you may need to write a script that leaves behind a marker file.  Then the command to ask docker to run might be certbot renew && test -f <marker file>.
Other notes
Just a heads-up that it can be simpler to move the TLS/SSL out of nginx entirely.  Both traefik and caddy can act as a HTTPS gateway ontop of an unencrypted HTTP backend.  They both nativly support Letsencrypt, meaning you just don't need to worry about handling the certificate renewal and HTTPS server config reload... it's all done for you. My personal preference is Traefik
